# PyAutoGui how to write special characters

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

I am new in python and I want to make writing bot with PyAutoGui. It works good but it cant write character like this "č", "š", "ř", "ž".How to write this special symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some time I finally know how to do this. I just use another plugin "keyboard"